# How to pass Tapped event to sibling in the same canvas?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have two controls within a `Canvas`, one of them overlapping the other (in the z-order). `Tapped` events received by the control at the front will be routed back to the parent `Canvas` by default.

However, I want the control at the front to ignore the event and have it be received by the control at the back. From searching around in SO, I find that we can't 'simulate' a tap to the background control in any way, so how can I do this ?

**tl;dr** How can an event be routed to a sibling instead of back to the parent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`IsHitTestVisible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.ishittestvisible(v=win.10).aspx) property. For example, here is a XAML fragment:

```
<Canvas>
  <Rectangle Width="200" Height="200" 
             Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100" 
             Fill="Red" Tapped="Rectangle_Tapped"/>
  <Rectangle Width="200" Height="200" 
             Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="200" 
             Fill="Blue" IsHitTestVisible="False" 
             Opacity="0.5"/>
</Canvas>
```

And the matching code:

```
private void Rectangle_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  new MessageDialog("Ouch!").ShowAsync();
}
```

Now if you tap either the red part of the screen or the purple part of the screen, you will see the dialog.